# Object tracking program does not show tracked points in the output image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to track an object in a video frame but to do so I have to initialize good features to track my object.
So, I have a .mp4 file, I retained the blue channel of the first frame and I obtained the first frame. I then went on to create my binary mask by extracting my region of interest from the first frame and it was specified that my ROI lies within [300,400] on the y-axis and [460,550] x-axis (which is the front side of the bus).

I then initialized 10 corner points by using `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` having a quality level of 0.01 and a minimum allowable distance of 10 pixels between corner points. I then tried to display these points on the RGB image however I am not getting any points. The reason as to why I do not know.
This is shown here:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vid = cv2.VideoCapture('Bus.mp4')
    
ret, frame = vid.read()

frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
blue_ch = frame[:,:,2]

mask = blue_ch[300:400,460:550]
prev_pts = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image = mask,maxCorners=10,qualityLevel=0.01,minDistance=10,blockSize=10)

blue_ch = np.array(blue_ch)
for i in prev_pts:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    cv2.circle(blue_ch,(x,y),3,255,-1)
    
plt.imshow(blue_ch)
```

Comment: `cv2` gives image as `numpy array` and you don't have to convert `numpy array` to `numpy array` in `blue_ch = np.array(blue_ch)`.

Comment: first you could check what you get in variables - ie. `print( prev_pts )` and `print(x,y)`. Maybe you simply don't see these circles because they are small or they have the same color as background. Did you try to draw them on original `frame` with `RGB` ?

Comment: when I draw circles on original RGB `frame` (and display `frame`) then I see small red dots in left top corner. On `blue_ch`  they are  small and similar to background so I can't see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates small yellow dots in top left corner. They are similar to background color so you may not see them.

When I draw on RGB `frame` then I get red dots which you can see on image

[image]

If I convert `blue_ch` to `RBG` before drawing

```
blue_ch = cv2.cvtColor(blue_ch, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

then I see

[image]

You get `mask = blue_ch[300:400, 460:550]` so when I add

```
y += 300
x += 460
```

then I get dots in correct place

[image]

---

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vid = cv2.VideoCapture('Bus.mp4')
    
ret, frame = vid.read()

frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
blue_ch = frame[:, :, 2]

mask = blue_ch[300:400, 460:550]
prev_pts = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image=mask, maxCorners=10, qualityLevel=0.01, minDistance=10, blockSize=10)

blue_ch = cv2.cvtColor(blue_ch, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
#blue_ch = np.array(blue_ch)

for i in prev_pts:
    x, y = i.ravel()
    y += 300
    x += 460 
    #print(x, y)
    cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), 3, 255, -1)
    cv2.circle(blue_ch, (int(x), int(y)), 3, 255, -1)
    
# --- display with matplot ---

plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(blue_ch)
plt.show()

# -- OR display with `cv2` ---

frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
blue_ch = cv2.cvtColor(blue_ch, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.imshow('blue_ch', blue_ch)

print("Press ESC to exit")
try:
    while cv2.waitKey(1) != 27: # ESC
        pass
except:    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you I did not even realize that the points were there. However I do not know why they were located on the top left corner, is there a reason for that? Because I would have not thought about adding those two lines y+=300 and y+=460 to properly place my points on the front of the bus.

Comment: I never used `goodFeaturesToTrack` but when I saw dots in corner but you said that you get `the front side of the bus` then I guessed that it could calculate position relative inside area `[300:400, 460:550]` and when I added `300` and `460` and I saw dots on bus then I was sure it is good idea.